# Webpage works locally, but only shows background colour if accessed through the web

Tags: html

A friend designed a website a very long time ago through Microsoft Publisher and has just gone back to discover that it won't load on the latest versions of chrome and firefox. The entire website works fine if the pages are loaded locally, but through the web, it only shows the background colour.

I am wondering if this is a coding issue, or something else. I can put up some code if need be, but it's very messy (as it came from publisher).

The website is hka.net.nz

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<link rel=File-List href="index_files/filelist.xml">
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
b\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<meta name="description"
content="houses design, residential, commercial and retail design">
<meta name="keywords"
content="houses design, residential, commercial and retail design">
<title>h a f e e d + k u b b a  architects</title>
<style>
<!--
 /* Style Definitions */
ol
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.25in;}
ul
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.25in;}
@page
    {size:8.2673in 11.6923in;}
-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="3089" fill="f" fillcolor="white [7]"
  strokecolor="black [0]">
  <v:fill color="white [7]" color2="white [7]" on="f"/>
  <v:stroke color="black [0]" color2="white [7]">
   <o:left v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
   <o:top v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
   <o:right v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
   <o:bottom v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
   <o:column v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  </v:stroke>
  <v:shadow color="#ccc [4]"/>
  <v:textbox inset="2.88pt,2.88pt,2.88pt,2.88pt"/>
  <o:colormru v:ext="edit" colors="black,#ddd,#969696,red,#c60,white"/>
 </o:shapedefaults><o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
  <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
 </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body link="#0066FF" vlink="#6633CC" bgcolor=black style='margin:0'>

<div style='position:absolute;width:7.9319in;height:6.2236in'>
<!--[if gte vml 1]><v:rect id="_x0000_s1267" href="index_files/4kHouse1.htm"
 style='position:absolute;left:81pt;top:354pt;width:282pt;height:92.96pt;
 z-index:138;mso-wrap-distance-left:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:2.88pt;
 mso-wrap-distance-right:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:2.88pt'
 o:preferrelative="t" filled="f" fillcolor="white [7]" stroked="f"
 strokecolor="black [0]" insetpen="t" o:cliptowrap="t">
 <v:fill color2="black [0]"/>
 <v:stroke color2="white [7]">
  <o:left v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" joinstyle="miter"
   insetpen="t"/>
  <o:top v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" joinstyle="miter"
   insetpen="t"/>
  <o:right v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" joinstyle="miter"
   insetpen="t"/>
  <o:bottom v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]" joinstyle="miter"
   insetpen="t"/>
  <o:column v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
 </v:stroke>
 <v:imagedata src="index_files/image538.jpg" o:title="Logo" cropbottom="19583f"
  gain="79922f"/>
 <v:shadow color="#ccc [4]"/>
 <v:path o:extrusionok="f" insetpenok="f"/>
 <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:rect><![endif]--><![if !vml]><span style='position:absolute;z-index:138;
left:108px;top:472px;width:376px;height:124px'><a
href="index_files/4kHouse1.htm"><img border=0 width=376 height=124
src="index_files/image5381.jpg" v:shapes="_x0000_s1267"></a></span><![endif]><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:line
 id="_x0000_s1268" href="index_files/4kuouse2.htm" style='position:absolute;
 z-index:139;mso-wrap-distance-left:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:2.88pt;
 mso-wrap-distance-right:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:2.88pt' from="5in,416.51pt"
 to="369pt,416.51pt" strokecolor="white [7]" o:cliptowrap="t">
 <v:stroke endarrow="block" endarrowwidth="wide" endarrowlength="long"
  color2="white [7]">
  <o:left v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:top v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:right v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:bottom v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:column v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
 </v:stroke>
 <v:shadow color="#ccc [4]"/>
 <v:path insetpenok="f"/>
</v:line><![endif]--><![if !vml]><span style='position:absolute;z-index:139;
left:479px;top:547px;width:15px;height:17px'><map name=MicrosoftOfficeMap0><area
shape=Rect coords="1, 8, 13, 9" href="index_files/4kuouse2.htm"></map><img
border=0 width=15 height=17 src="index_files/image642.gif"
usemap="#MicrosoftOfficeMap0" v:shapes="_x0000_s1268"></span><![endif]><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:rect
 id="_x0000_s1306" href="index_files/4kHouse1.htm" style='position:absolute;
 left:213pt;top:246pt;width:93pt;height:91.34pt;z-index:163;
 mso-wrap-distance-left:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:2.88pt;
 mso-wrap-distance-right:2.88pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:2.88pt'
 o:preferrelative="t" filled="f" fillcolor="white [7]" stroked="f"
 strokecolor="black [0]" o:cliptowrap="t">
 <v:fill color2="white [7]"/>
 <v:stroke color2="white [7]">
  <o:left v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:top v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:right v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:bottom v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
  <o:column v:ext="view" color="black [0]" color2="white [7]"/>
 </v:stroke>
 <v:imagedata src="index_files/image402.jpg" o:title="image537"/>
 <v:shadow color="#ccc [4]"/>
 <v:path o:extrusionok="f" insetpenok="f"/>
 <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:rect><![endif]--><![if !vml]><span style='position:absolute;z-index:163;
left:284px;top:328px;width:124px;height:122px'><a
href="index_files/4kHouse1.htm"><img border=0 width=124 height=122
src="index_files/image4021.jpg" v:shapes="_x0000_s1306"></a></span><![endif]>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess it is a coding issue ... or even could be something else ...

Comment: Use Firefox or Chrome and watch the 'Network' tab and/or error console.  One or the other might tell you about resources that failed to load.

Comment: View source in chrome or Mozilla. and click on all connected js, css file address(click on the link), MAKE SURE THAT LINK IS CORRECT...

Comment: [96 errors, 1 warning](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhka.net.nz&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing, but sounds like there is a JS script or CSS stylesheet missing or that has a local reference hardcoded, e.g.

```
<script src="C:\Local\Path\To\Script.js"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Local\Path\To\Stylesheet.css"/>
```

**Edit:** You should also check that you don't have JS errors if it depends on JavaScript for initialization.
Open the web developer console or Firebug to check for scripting errors.

**EDIT:** You're full of [IE-specific conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that hide contents from other browsers.

Comment: Double-checking to see if this is the case, thanks.

Comment: <link rel=File-List href="index_files/filelist.xml">

That is what I have on the index page. Every file but the index page is in the one folder, the index page being one level higher.

Comment: 1) Use firebug to check for JS errors and/or network requests that may have failed (missing files will trigger a 404 Not Found error).
2) Check that you actually uploaded the file and remember that names are case sensitive in Linux/Unix environments.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I've installed Firebug, and no errors come up anywhere. I will double check with him to see if he's uploaded all files correctly.

Comment: Also should have mentioned, the website works fine on IE6. It just doesn't function on the latest browsers.

Comment: Using some goddamn ActiveX control, maybe?

Comment: Anyway, it would be much easier if we could see the actual webpage, or the code

Comment: It's just really messy, I'll put in the code now.

Comment: Just read your edit, I'll go have a look over those and remove them so it works on other browsers. Thankyou very much for your help!

Comment: Worse, those namespaced elements are defined only within IE browsers, I think: <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">.
I think you're better off recoding the page from scratch.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Okay yep sorry I understand now.